# Extract filename from string using Regex

Tags: regex

I have a string that I extracted from URL that I'm trying to cleanup.  Here's the string:

```
/Portals/0/Documents/MFG_Datasheet_Work%20and%20Asset.pdf?ver=2018-03-18-111121-810
```

I'm trying to extract the filename after /Documents/ and remove the "?ver=" and everything after it to just pull in the PDF filename.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let str = "/Portals/0/Documents/MFG_Datasheet_Work%20and%20Asset.pdf?ver=2018-03-18-111121-810"
    console.log(str.match(/.*\/([^?]+).*/))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.*/([^?]+).*
```

Explanation:

```
.*/        # anything up to the last slash
([^?]+)    # store anything thereafter in a group,
           # up until an optional question mark
.*         # optional rest (question mark and everything thereafter)
```

Depending on the implementation language, the replacement value you want could be `$1` (e.g. in Java). [See it online](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyy6nff6r).